# Using Jenkins variables/parameters in Python Script with os.path.join

Tags: python, variables, jenkins, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to learn how to use variables from Jenkins in Python scripts. I've already learned that I need to call the variables, but I'm not sure how to implement them in the case of using os.path.join().

I'm not a developer; I'm a technical writer. This code was written by somebody else. I'm just trying to adapt the Jenkins scripts so they are parameterized so we don't have to modify the Python scripts for every release.

I'm using inline Jenkins python scripts inside a Jenkins job. The Jenkins string parameters are "BranchID" and "BranchIDShort". I've looked through many questions that talk about how you have to establish the variables in the Python script, but with the case of os.path.join(),I'm not sure what to do.

Here is the original code. I added the part where we establish the variables from the Jenkins parameters, but I don't know how to use them in the os.path.join() function.

```
# Delete previous builds.

import os
import shutil

BranchID = os.getenv("BranchID")
BranchIDshort = os.getenv("BranchIDshort")

print "Delete any output from a previous build."
if os.path.exists(os.path.join("C:\\Doc192CS", "Output")):
    shutil.rmtree(os.path.join("C:\\Doc192CS", "Output"))
```

I expect output like: c:\Doc192CS\Output

I am afraid that if I do the following code:

```
if os.path.exists(os.path.join("C:\\Doc",BranchIDshort,"CS", "Output")):
    shutil.rmtree(os.path.join("C:\\Doc",BranchIDshort,"CS", "Output"))
```

I'll get: c:\Doc\192\CS\Output.

Is there a way to use the BranchIDshort variable in this context to get the output c:\Doc192CS\Output?

Comment: Indeed you're right. What you would want to do is rather: `os.path.exists(os.path.join("C:\\","Doc{}CS".format(BranchIDshort),"Output"))` (in short use a format string for the 2nd argument)

Comment: This should have been an answer. It is exactly what I needed. Thank you. If I ever meet you in person, let me buy you a drink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @Adonis gave the correct solution as a comment. Here is what he said:

> Indeed you're right. What you would want to do is rather:
>   `os.path.exists(os.path.join("C:\\","Doc{}CS".format(BranchIDshort),"Output"))`
>   (in short use a format string for the 2nd argument)

So the complete corrected code is:

```
import os
import shutil

BranchID = os.getenv("BranchID")
BranchIDshort = os.getenv("BranchIDshort")

print "Delete any output from a previous build."
if os.path.exists(os.path.join("C:\\Doc{}CS".format(BranchIDshort), "Output")):
    shutil.rmtree(os.path.join("C:\\Doc{}CS".format(BranchIDshort), "Output"))
```

Thank you, @Adonis!